# Sending dinner details to the user based on email id that exist in array

Tags: php, email, cron

I am working on a cron job script and the purpose of the script is to send dinner details to the user, now the user should ONLY get the dinner details in email that they are attending.

Since it is a cron job so what happens is the query pulls all the dinners from database and puts the result in an `array()` which looks like this.

```
CronController.php on line 79:
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:19 [▼
    "request_id" => "50"
    "dinner_id" => "35"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_status" => "pending"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "guest_first_name" => "x"
    "guest_last_name" => "y"
    "guest_user_id" => "78"
    "dinner_host" => "77"
    "host_email" => "xyz@example2.com"
    "host_first_name" => "News 12"
    "host_last_name" => "News 12"
    "host_user_id" => 55
  ]
  1 => array:19 [▼
    "request_id" => "50"
    "dinner_id" => "35"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_status" => "pending"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-27T10:00:00"
    "guest_first_name" => "x"
    "guest_last_name" => "y"
    "guest_user_id" => "78"
    "dinner_host" => "77"
    "host_email" => "abcd@example1.com"
    "host_first_name" => "Demo First"
    "host_last_name" => "Demo Last"
    "host_user_id" => 77
  ]
  2 => array:19 [▼
    "request_id" => "51"
    "dinner_id" => "36"
    "dinner_name" => "Black Tie"
    "dinner_status" => "pending"
    "dinner_date" => "2016-05-16T10:00:00"
    "guest_first_name" => "x"
    "guest_last_name" => "y"
    "guest_user_id" => "78"
    "dinner_host" => "77"
    "host_email" => "abcd@example1.com"
    "host_first_name" => "Demo First"
    "host_last_name" => "Demo Last"
    "host_user_id" => 77
  ]
]
```

Now you will notice `host_email` for the first its `xyz@example2.com` so this person should only get that dinner details and not the second and third, similarly for the second and third result you will notice the `host_email` is same `abcd@example1.com` so this user should get only 1 email containing details of both dinners.

I have in past generated emails in PHP but never in this way so I am stuck on how to even begin this. I will really appreciate any help in this.

Comment: is there any unique id?

Comment: @RuchishParikh not in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over your array to rearrange it.

```
$mails = array();
foreach ($array as $messageArray) {
    $mails[$messageArray['host_email']][] = $messageArray;
}
```

Now you have your messages grouped by host_email and can just iterate over it and stack the messages.

Like this:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "host_email" => "test@dfsd.com",
        "text" => "hello you",
    ),
    array(
        "host_email" => "SomeoneElse@what.uk",
        "text" => "I am hungry",
    ),
    array(
        "host_email" => "test@dfsd.com",
        "text" => "hello you 2",
    ),
);

$mails = array();
foreach ($array as $messageArray) {
    $mails[$messageArray['host_email']][] = $messageArray;
}

// outer Loop to create mailheader and to send the mail after creating the message
foreach ($mails as $to=> $messages) {

    $subject = 'eating';
    $mailHeader = '...';
    $mailBody = '';

    // inner loop to stick the messages together that have the same recipent
    foreach ($messages as $value) {
        $mailBody .= $value['text'] . "\n\r";
    }

    mail($to, $subject, $mailBody, $mailHeader);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be giving me error of `Notice: Undefined index: host_email`

Comment: actually it worked, now i have an array grouped by email id, so to send email, i should do another foreach?

Comment: Yeah, you first iterate over $mails and within that loop you iterate over the array with the messages to build your complete message for the email. After the inner loop [building the messages for the host_email] is done you send the mail and the next iteration of the outer loop [sending the differen emails] can start.

Comment: could you please show the code sample as that will really to help understand it